# How do I get permissions to access files using bootable live USB Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, live-usb

Initially I had windows 7 in my PC. I installed Ubuntu Kylin and it was working properly at first. After one day it stopped working and the hard drive now has only one partition.

I've logged in to my computer using bootable Ubuntu USB drive but I can't access my files. It says

> you do not have permissions necessary to view the contents.

I want to copy my contents to another drive. How can I do it?

Comment: Please anyone can tell me how to fix this problem????

Comment: Have you tried `sudo su` and `nautilus` from Ubuntu live usb?

Comment: Yes I tried but it didn't work. After I tried to change owner and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Change the user as command line chown $USER then u can access it.